# Sharepoint 2007: Show counter for rows in a list

Tags: list, list-view

Is there any way to show a counter for the number of rows in a list in SharePoint 2007? I know that it is possible to display a counter for entries in a column by creating/modifying views. However, this will not count all the rows if there are blank entries in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every item must have ID so you can use that field to count the number of rows.

1. Modify a View that contains the ID field
2. Go to Totals
3. For the ID field choose Count